# Annoying x-axis overflow creating whitespace on chrome mobile browser

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, mobile, overflow

I have just almost finished a simple portfolio site for myself and, ironically, I can't get rid of the whitespace on the right hand side of the screen on chrome mobile browser. It's not there in firefox or duckduckgo browser.

The site is Tierneywebdevelopment.com.

I've tried all of these, which remain in the css:

```
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  scrollbar-width: thick;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

I've downloaded overflow detector chrome extension and it says no elements exceed their parents' width.

Anyone have any ideas or fixes?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the `box-sizing: border-box` prop to `html,body` and see if the probleme persists

Comment: Thanks, have now given it a try and no such luck :/